# Combine the data of two files having same column using awk

Tags: awk

I have two files: file1 and file2. i want to combine the time between file1 and file2 with common column as 1 and 2. I need to create a separate file which contains the file1 data and file2 mapping time column. But for some entires(see BOLD TEXT) its matching the same line from file2. Whats wrong in my command? is there any way to get the expected output?

Note: there can be more than 2 entries as shown in the bold text. column1 and column2 entries can be same while only time changes.

file 1

9950 | p | 2021-02-27 14:16:21.905 
9951 | q | 2021-02-27 14:16:28.845 
**9954 | r | 2021-02-27 14:17:21.884 

9954 | r | 2021-02-27 14:19:46.775** 

9956 | y | 2021-02-27 14:20:20.830 
9957 | z | 2021-02-27 14:20:27.325

file 2

9950 | p | 2021-02-27 14:16:22.086 
9951 | q | 2021-02-27 14:16:29.033 
**9954 | r | 2021-02-27 14:17:22.072 

9954 | r | 2021-02-27 14:19:46.956** 

9956 | y | 2021-02-27 14:20:21.018 
9957 | z | 2021-02-27 14:20:27.512

command:

```
 awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next} a[$1,$2]{print $0"\t"a[$1,$2]}' file2 file1
```

Output:

9950 | p | 2021-02-27 14:16:21.905 | 2021-02-27 14:16:22.086 
9951 | q | 2021-02-27 14:16:28.845 | 2021-02-27 14:16:29.033 
**9954 | r | 2021-02-27 14:17:21.884 | 2021-02-27 14:19:46.956 

9954 | r | 2021-02-27 14:19:46.775 | 2021-02-27 14:19:46.956** 

9956 | x | 2021-02-27 14:20:20.830 | 2021-02-27 14:20:21.018 
9957 | y | 2021-02-27 14:20:27.325 | 2021-02-27 14:20:27.512

Expected output:

9950 | p | 2021-02-27 14:16:21.905 | 2021-02-27 14:16:22.086 
9951 | q | 2021-02-27 14:16:28.845 | 2021-02-27 14:16:29.033 
**9954 | r | 2021-02-27 14:17:21.884 | 2021-02-27 14:17:22.072 

9954 | r | 2021-02-27 14:19:46.775 | 2021-02-27 14:19:46.956** 

9956 | x | 2021-02-27 14:20:20.830 | 2021-02-27 14:20:21.018 
9957 | y | 2021-02-27 14:20:27.325 | 2021-02-27 14:20:27.512

Comment: Your key `$1,$2` is not unique. Only the _last_ value from file2 will be stored in the `a` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to James Brown's answer, but only needing to keep one "count" array, and using $1 plus $2 for the key

```sh
gawk -F '|' '
    FNR == 1 {delete count}
    {key = $1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP (++count[$1,$2])}
    FILENAME == ARGV[1] {time[key] = $3; next}
    key in time {print $0, FS, time[key]}
' file2 file1
```

Comment: Hey @glenn. Thanks for your answer. Its working perfectly in my scenario. Can you plase explain me the above gawk command.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=" [|] "
    OFS=" | "
}
NR==FNR {
    a[$1,++c[$1]]=$0          # c[$1] is an instance counter array, 
    next                      # unique for each $1
}
{
    print a[$1,++d[$1]],$NF   # so is d[$1]
}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
9950 | p | 2021-02-27 14:16:21.905 | 2021-02-27 14:16:22.086
9951 | q | 2021-02-27 14:16:28.845 | 2021-02-27 14:16:29.033
9954 | r | 2021-02-27 14:17:21.884 | 2021-02-27 14:17:22.072
9954 | r | 2021-02-27 14:19:46.775 | 2021-02-27 14:19:46.956
...
```

**Updated** with request from comments:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=" [|] "
    OFS=" | "
}
NR==FNR {
    a[$1,++c[$1]]=$0          # c[$1] is an instance counter array, 
    next                      # unique for each $1
}
(($1,++d[$1]) in a) {         # only output if match in both files
    print a[$1,d[$1]],$NF     # so is d[$1]
}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Hii, thanks for the solution. but there one thing when there is no mapping in request lets say 9951 transaction doesn't exists in file1 but it exists in file2. then i want to drop that entry. how can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

If this isn't all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output including cases that this doesn't work for:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{$7=$8=$9=""; $0=$0; $1=$1}1'
9950 | p | 2021-02-27 14:16:21.905 | 2021-02-27 14:16:22.086
9951 | q | 2021-02-27 14:16:28.845 | 2021-02-27 14:16:29.033
9954 | r | 2021-02-27 14:17:21.884 | 2021-02-27 14:17:22.072
9954 | r | 2021-02-27 14:19:46.775 | 2021-02-27 14:19:46.956
9956 | y | 2021-02-27 14:20:20.830 | 2021-02-27 14:20:21.018
9957 | z | 2021-02-27 14:20:27.325 | 2021-02-27 14:20:27.512
```

In the above `$7=$8=$9=""` set those fields to `NULL` strings but does not change how many fields are in `$0`, then `$0=$0` causes awk to resplit `$0` thereby removing those as individual fields but not altering the white space around where they existed, then `$1=$1` causes awk to reconstruct `$0` from its fields replacing every string  that matches `FS` (i.e. contiguous white space) with the string that matches `OFS` (i.e. a single blank char). For example (with `| tr ' ' '-'` added to make the spaces more clearly visible):

```
$ echo 'a b c' | awk '{print NF, $0}' | tr ' ' '-'
3-a-b-c
$ echo 'a b c' | awk '{$2=""; print NF, $0}' | tr ' ' '-'
3-a--c
$ echo 'a b c' | awk '{$2=""; $0=$0; print NF, $0}' | tr ' ' '-'
2-a--c
$ echo 'a b c' | awk '{$2=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; print NF, $0}' | tr ' ' '-'
2-a-c
```

Comment: Can you talk about how using _both_ `$0=$0` and `$1=$1` works to remove extraneous spaces?